# implications of having a site in full https

Tags: asp.net, performance, security, https, asp.net-mvc-4

I am currently developing an MVC4 web application for eCommerce. The site will contain a login and users can visit the site, input their details and submit orders etc. This is a traditional eCommerce site.

To boost the security of the site, I am looking to set up the entire site in https. As the user will be supplying their log in credentials and storing personal information in cookies, I would like the site to be fully secured.

I have concerns though, these being if I set up the site in https, will it detriment performance? Will it impact negatively on search engine optimization? Are there any other implications of having an entire site in https?

I use output caching to cache the content of my views - with https will these still get cached?

I have been reviewing security guidelines and documentation, such as [this](http://asafaweb.com/OWASP%20Top%2010%20for%20.NET%20developers.pdf) from OWASP and they recommend this. Also, I see that sites such as twitter are fully https.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, no - whole-site encryption is not a problem for performance.

(Just make sure you disable SSL 2.0 on your server, as it's vulnerable to the BEAST attack; you should use TLS 1.0 or SSL3.0 which have been supported by pretty much every browser since 2000).

The performance issues were a problem years ago, but not anymore. Modern servers have the capacity to deal with the encryption of hundreds of requests and responses every second.

You haven't mentioned deploying a load-balancer or failover system, which implies your site won't be subject to thousands of pageviews every second. That's when you need to start using SSL offloaders - but you're okay for now.

Output caching is not affected by encryption - just make sure you're not serving one person's output to another (i.e. cache a shopping cart or banking details in `Session` or with the Session ID in the `Cache` key).

Comment: Yes my web application will be load balanced across multiple web servers - are there implications to such?

Comment: How are you load-balancing? I strongly recommend getting a hardware load-balancer with built-in SSL offloading, which will certainly reduce the burden on your servers. I'm not sure how best to deploy software-based load-balancing without offloading SSL.